# How to execute an awk script in C program?

Tags: c, awk

I have a C program like passing argument in family of exec function to execute an `awk` script?
Is there is any way to execute one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How many different ways do you want?

- [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) is probably the easiest way.
- [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) and [`pclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pclose.html) might be appropriate if you want to supply input to the program or get the output from it.
- [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) and one of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execv.html) family of functions, possibly with [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html).
- [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) if you like convoluted mechanisms.

With `system()` and `popen()`, you'll convert the command and arguments into a string which will be parsed by a shell. With the other options, you specify the command name and the arguments as separate strings.  Other details depend on which option you're using, but any of them can be made to work.